# Preventing strangers accessing WEBRTC pages

Tags: grails, webrtc

I am creating a sample application to tryout `WEBRTC`. I came across a [tutorial](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/meeting/) that explains the process. I tried copying the code and it seems to work.

Question is:

I ONLY want a few people to access the page that containing the stream. How can i prevent other unauthorised users from accessing my page. A tutorial that walks through the process would be ideal.

the language i am using to develop is `Grails`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [authentication plugin for the grails](http://grails.org/plugin/authentication) to deny unauthorized request. You can even use Socket.io over Node.js to prevent unauthorized users where you can check "userid":

```
// socket.io nodejs side code
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     var userid = socket.handshake.query.userid;
     // verify userid
     if (typeof objUserArrays[userid] == 'undefined') {
         // don't broadcast messages; so that user can NEVER join any room.
         return;
     }
 });
```

and browser side code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://your-domain.com/?userid=something');
```

For last snippet; you can check [meeting.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/meeting#custom-signaling-channel)'s `openSignalingChannel` method:

```
meeting.openSignalingChannel = function(callback) {
    return io.connect('http://your-domain.com/?userid=something').on('message', callback);
};
```